# Yes I have done it before today

Tags: present-perfect

> Question : have you done the Homework?
>
> Answer   : Yes I have done it before today..

Is it Correct if I did my homework yesterday itself and I use present perfect answer the question? Since I can't say yesterday in present perfect, can I say before today?

Comment: *Correct* in what way?

Comment: Can I use present perfect to answer the question since I cant use yesterday in present perfect . can I say before today instead of yesterday? @Lawrence

Comment: It sounds a bit odd. Perhaps it's because that uses *have* as a straight verb (I have [*done whatever*]), as opposed to an auxiliary verb (*have done*). It seems to answer a question like "Have you ever done done this?" rather than the one your question poses. However, I'm not a linguist, so I'll leave it to the more technically-minded among us to present a proper answer. There may also be material already in the database. Click the [tag:present-perfect] tag to get a list of those questions to look at.

Comment: What does "before today" mean? Is it yesterday? Is it last night? Is it two days ago? Maybe you meant to say "***earlier*** today"?

Comment: Probably technically "correct" from a grammar standpoint, but quite ambiguous.  Should only be used if the intent is to create confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the main issue is that you don't know how to combine an explicit mention of *yesterday* with the present perfect. The standard way of doing it is by making *yesterday* a **supplement**, something not integrated into the syntactic structure of the sentence. Like this:

Q: *Have you done your homework?*
A: *Yes I have, **yesterday**.*

**Discussion**

It is true that

> Time adjuncts like *last week, two minutes ago*, etc., which refer to times wholly before now, are incompatible with the present perfect.

([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 143). The reson is that

> The present perfect involves reference to both past and present time: it is concerned with a time-span beginning in the past and extending up to now. It is not used in contexts where the 'now' component of this is explicitly or implicitly excluded.

Nevertheless, note that such adjuncts *are* allowed if they appear as **supplements** (something that is not integrated into the syntactical structure of the sentence). Thus, we are allowed to say

A: *Yes I have, yesterday.*

Here are some examples of similar usage from published literature (the supplemental time adjunct is in boldface):

> *"Have you been there?" "Yes I have, **last time he was in London**."* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZLWEBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA277&dq=%22yes%20I%20have%2C%20last%22&pg=PA277#v=onepage&q=%22yes%20I%20have,%20last%22&f=false)
>   *'Yes, we have, **yesterday**.'* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=gj2pBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT46&dq=%22Yes%20we%20have%2C%20yesterday%22&pg=PT46#v=onepage&q=%22Yes%20we%20have,%20yesterday%22&f=false)
>   *"Yes, they have, **on that fateful day**."* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=PZxPAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA201&dq=%22Yes%20they%20have%2C%20on%22&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q=%22Yes%20they%20have,%20on%22&f=false)
>   *"Yes Ivana she has, **some five years ago.**"* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=wXygQqoE-9IC&lpg=PA44&dq=%22Yes%20she%20has%2C%20*%20ago%22&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q=%22Yes%20Ivana%20she%20has,%20some%20five%20years%20ago.%22&f=false)
>   *"Yes, she has. **Last night**."* ([source.](https://books.google.com/books?id=YHyYDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT267&dq=%22yes%20she%20has%2C%20last%22&pg=PT267#v=onepage&q=%22yes%20she%20has,%20last%22&f=false) Here the temporal adjunct appears on its own as a verbless and subjectless sentence, which could equally well appear as a supplement.)

The reason why this works is that supplements are only required to be **semantically** compatible with the rest of the sentence, whereas integrated parts of the sentence must be syntactically compatible as well. CGEL explains it like this (pp. 1351-1352):

> [Integrated constructions require] that the complement be syntactically licensed, whereas in supplementation it is, as we said above, a matter of semantic compatibility. Compare:
>
> [7]  i  a.  *The stipulation that Harry could not touch the money until he was eighteen
>
>                  annoyed him enormously.* 
>             b.  **The codicil that Harry could not touch the money until he was eighteen
>
>                  annoyed him enormously.* 
>         ii  a.  *This stipulation—that Harry could not touch the money until he was
>
>                  eighteen—annoyed him enormously.* 
>             b.  *The codicil in the will—that Harry could not touch the money until he was
>
>                  eighteen—annoyed him enormously.*

A *codicil* is 'an addition or supplement that explains, modifies, or revokes a will or part of one' (see e.g. [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/codicil)). CGEL continues:

> The examples in [i] belong to the integrated head + complement construction. *Stipulation* licenses a declarative complement, but *codicil* does not: hence the ungrammaticality of [ib]. In [ii] the content clause is a supplement, interpreted as specifying the content of its anchor NP [noun phrase; an **anchor** is what the supplement is related to semantically, but not syntactically]. And this time the *codicil* example is acceptable: the NP it heads denotes an addition to a will and hence has propositional content which can be specified by a declarative content clause.

**Why the sentence you tried doesn't work**

Now let's discuss why

[1] *I have done it before today.*

doesn't work in your case.

It is an acceptable sentence of English, but it is probably not how that conversation would actually go. In your context, it sounds awkward. To explain why, let's consider the following sentence:

[2] *I have borrowed this car three times before today.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=aiALBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA4&dq=%22before%20today%22&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22I've%20borrowed%20this%20car%20three%20times%20before%20today%22&f=false)

This implies that the speaker borrowed the car a total of *four* times: three times before today, and then *also* today.

So [1] would make sense in the following situation: Kim and Alex have just completed some activity that lots of people find frightening although it is actually perfectly safe. It is Alex's first time doing that, and he got really scared. Kim, however, was calm, and Alex is wondering how Kim managed to stay so calm. Kim says, 'Oh, I've done it before today.'

**What a native speaker would actually say**

While *Yes I have, yesterday* is prefectly fine, other responses to *Have you done your homework?* are perheps even more likely:

*Yes, I have.*
*Yes, I did it yesterday.*

Note that especially in American English, the question itself could be in the preterite:

***Did*** you **do** your homework?

**Is this is case of ellipsis?**

It has been suggested that what we have here is a case of ellipsis, i.e. that [3] i is an ellipted version of [3] ii, where the boldfaced words in ii are the ones that were ellipted, while '___'s mark the positions in i where the ellipsis occured:

[3]   i  *Yes I have ___, ___ yesterday.*
       ii  *Yes I have **done it**, **I did it** yesterday.*

An important thing to realize about ellipsis is that it should be invoked only when other kinds of analyses fail—the burden on proof is on those who claim something *is* an ellipsis, not those who claim it is not. This follows from principle that the elliptical construction must be grammatically 'defective': therefore, if it can be shown that a construction is **not** 'defective', then it is not an instance of ellipsis. There are other principles as well. [ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582517346) gives five such principles (pp. 884-887):

(a) The ellipted words are precisely recoverable;
(b) The elliptical construction is grammatically 'defective';
(c) The insertion of the missing words results in a grammatical
       sentence with the same meaning as the original sentence;
(d) The missing word(s) are textually recoverable, and;
(e) are present in the text in exactly the same form.

In light of these, let's compare [3] with a pradigmatic case of ellipsis:

[4]  i  A:  *You had better stay at home.*    B:  *Yes, I'd better.*
 
      ii                                                                  B:  *Yes, I'd better **stay at home**.*

(a) In [4], *stay at home* is the only realistic option for the ellipted part. Not so in [3]. Any of the following would also work:

*done my homework, I did/finished it*
*done it, I did/finished my homework*
*done my homework, I did/finished my homework*
*done my homework, I did/finished my homework*

and also

*done it, I was done with it*

and many others.

(b) In [4], i is indeed grammatically defective: *had better* requires a complement. [3] i, however, is not defective, because *yesterday* is a supplement (this is what I explained in the main part of my answer).

(c) This one is OK in [4]. It *may* be OK in [3]. The problem is that [3] ii consists of two independent clauses connected by just a comma. Normally this is not OK: independent clauses should either be explicitly coordinated by a connection (e.g. *since*) or else joined by a semi-colon. As it is, it looks like a comma splice. However, *maybe* we can say that [3] ii is an instance of asyndetic coordination.

(d) and (e) Definitiely satisfied in [4]. Maybe it is also OK in [3]. Ellipsis normally allows trivial changes to accomodate agreement for number, person, and tense. For example, consider

*She hasn't written it yet, but I'm sure she soon will ___*,

where the position of the ellipted part is indicated by '___'. What is ellipted (i.e. what should appear in place of '___') is *write it*, even though what we have in the first part is *written it*.

So *perhaps* it is not that big a deal that we have two ellipses, both of the verb ***do**, which is the present perfect in the first ellipsis, but in the preterite in the second. Note that in the second ellipsis, we have also ellipted the subject, *I*.

In the end, I would say that on ballance, the ellipsis analysis in [3] does not look more persuasive than my original suggestion that *yesterday* is a supplement. Properties (a) and (b) are the most important characteristics of ellipses, and they do not seem to hold for [3].

Comment: If someone had asked me "Have you done your homework?", I would probably have answered, "Yes, I did it yesterday."  Or I might have said, "Yes, I have."  In the second case, "...done my homework" is "understood".

Comment: @tautophile Agreed; what you say is what a native speaker is most likely to say in this situation. I interpreted the OP's question as mostly about how to combine *yesterday* with the present perfect.  I think that's an interesting question, given that time adjunct like *yesterday* are not licensed by the present perfect. And yet we do often combine the two, and I thought it would be interesting to explain how we do that. But I have included your comments in the answer (the new last section, 'What a native speaker would actually say'). Thanks!

Comment: @linguisticturn Thank you so much .. first time i got my answer here.. I fully understood your explanation.. I doubt is cleared now.

Comment: @TheMdsami33 You're welcome! (BTW, it should be ***My** doubt is cleared now.* :) )

Comment: @linguisticturn by mistake I typed that.. last question  , A witness claimed he saw a thief  or A witness claimed he had seen a thief...

newspaper it was written : A witness claimed he saw a theif.

I think this is Reported Speech , and A witness claimed he had seen a thief , is correct?

Comment: @TheMdsami33 On an ESL exam, *if the question was about reported speech*, then yes, you'd need the backshift to past perfect. But the newspaper article is not claiming to be reporting the witness's speech, but rather just the *content* of that speech. And unlike ESL (English as a Second Language) students on an exam, newspapers are allowed to **paraphrase**. Now, even in paraphrases, there is a legitimate question here about whether here one should use the past perfect or the simple past tense. But that should be the subject of another question.

Comment: @linguisticturn , just tell me can I say Watchman claimed he saw a thief yesterday?? while speaking to any native man, or it will sound awkward to native english speaker?  because I even cannot say watchman claimed he had seen thief yesterday as well , since with past perfect i cannot use yesterday...

Comment: Not sure why you think you can't use *yesterday* with the past perfect... At any rate, both of these are acceptable: *Earlier today, the watchman claimed he saw a thief yesterday*; *Earlier today, the watchman claimed he had seen a thief yesterday*. Their grammatical analysis would be different, and only the latter could count as 'reported speech' for the purposes of an ESL exam. But they are both perfectly fine English sentences.

Comment: As far as *yesterday* with the past perfect: note that the past perfect **neutralizes** the difference between perfect and 'simple' past: past perfect is the correct 'past in the past' form for **both** the present perfect and the simple past tense.

Comment: @linguisticturn We don`t "combine" yesterday " with the present perfect tense. It`s called - ellipsis. We use it to avoid unnecessary repetition of words. For example - have you been there ? - yes, I have, ( I was there yesterday ) yesterday. Have you seen that movie ? - yes, I have, ( I saw it 2 years ago ) 2 years ago. Check this out - https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-ellipsis.html

Comment: @Gio I looked at it carefully, and at the end, I don't think evidence favors that analysis. I give my reasons  in the last section of my answer.  I also looked at *all* examples of ellipsis covered in CGEL, and none matches this one.

Comment: @Gio However, now I have looked at all the examples in ComGEL, and now I am less sure. On the one hand, they say that the following is an instance of ellipsis: *I caught the train—just.* This is ellipsis in a supplemental clause, just like in our case.  On the other hand, they say 'Appended clauses consisting of an adverbial only are closely related to nonrestrictive adverbials (cf15.23): *I only met him once —at your place.*' In 15.23 they don't mention ellipsis, however.  So now I'm a bit confused what they would say about our case. I need to think about this some more.